# How to retrieve a video from the UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

In my APP im saving the video to photolibrary using UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum. I am getting the path of the video but i am not able to play this video. Can any 1 help me with this on how to retrieve the saved video.Thanks in advance.I used the Code shown below.

```
-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

  if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];

} else {
    picker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString *)kUTTypeImage, nil];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

      NSString *tempFilePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
      UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(tempFilePath, self,  @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
      NSLog(@"temp path %@",tempFilePath);
      [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempFilePath];
and Play the url using: "MPMoviePlayerController"

Answer (score 1):

The path that is returned by this function needs a suffix. try this

```
NSString *videoPath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://localhost%@", videoPath]];
```